# How can I receive a list of dictionaries in djano?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-database, django-jsonfield

Hello I am working on a djago project and I want to recieve a list of dictionaries just like this:
`[{1: 20}, {2:30}, {3: 50}, ......]`
here the `key` is the `id of the product`and `value` is `price`
And the code below is just receiving a `single dictionary` like this
`{"id": 1, "price" : 20}`
I want to change it to something look like I mentioned above

```
 list_of_objects = []
        try:
            id = int(request.payload.get("id"))
            price = int(request.payload.get("price"))
            list_of_objects.append({
                "id" : id,
                "price" : price
            })
        except ValueError:
            return response.bad_request("Invalid price, %s, should be in whole dollars" % price)
```

I don't know how to do it
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        list_of_objects = []
        try:
            id = int(request.payload.get("id"))
            price = int(request.payload.get("price"))
            list_of_objects.append({
                id: price   # here changes
            })
        except ValueError:
            return response.bad_request("Invalid price, %s, should be in whole dollars" % price)
```

Comment: It doesn't accept multiple dictionaries. I tried it

Comment: I want to send ```{id: price, id: price, ...}``` like this

Comment: iterate the dictionary and then append in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    your_dict = {}
    try:
        id = int(request.payload.get("id"))
        price = int(request.payload.get("price"))
        your_dict[id] = price
    except ValueError:
        return response.bad_request("Invalid price, %s, should be in whole dollars" % price)
```

Comment: This is the error: "argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Comment: I want to send dictionary like this ```{id: price, id: price, ....}```

Comment: The error is because the `payload` dictionary doesn't have `id` or `price`. you can make it safer using:    
    `id = int(request.payload.get("id"), "")`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. If you want your prices to be exactly like this `{id: price, id: price, ....}`, then you should have all your `price`s and `id`s and then convert them to dictionary. but with getting `id` and `price` from `payload`, you only have one item to convert to dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me; I did the same thing a little while ago.

```
request_dict = dict(request.payload)
```

I hope it works for you too.